# Median of Medians vs TreeMap

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering if using a `TreeMap` to go through the array of numbers and get a sorted result be a better option than using the Median of Medians algorithm to find the K-th largest element in an unsorted array? Wont both work in linear time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wont both work in linear time?

Of course they would: once the data is in a tree map, finding K-order statistics is an O(N) operation<sup>*</sup>. Moreover, chances are, the one operating on `TreeMap` would have a smaller constant factor, unless you choose to write the sorted container out into an array.

The catch is that building `TreeMap` is O(N*log<sub>2</sub>N), while Median of Medians algorithm works on unsorted data, thus requiring no preliminary steps. Therefore, using `TreeMap` on previously unordered collection would be asymptotically more expensive.

<sup>*</sup> You can make it an O(log<sub>2</sub>N) by augmenting tree nodes with the count of items in each subtree.

Comment: I think  finding k-order statistic in treemap is O(log(N)) not O(N)

Comment: @Odomontois I think you need to augment the tree with the size of each subtree in order to get K-order-stat in O(Log N).

Comment: You probably right for very general case. But it worth to say that treemaps already has this information in may implementations like Haskell's `Map` or Scala's `TreeMap`.

Comment: Did not consider the augmentation approach. Thanks a lot guys!